# Algorithm to decompose set of timestamps into subsets with even temporal spacing

Tags: algorithm

I have a dataset containing > 100,000 records where each record has a timestamp.

This dataset has been aggregated from several "controller" nodes which each collect their data from a set of children nodes.  Each controller collects these records periodically, (e.g. once every 5 minutes or once every 10 minutes), and it is the *controller* that applies the timestamp to the records.

---

**E.g:**

Controller One might have 20 records timestamped at time `t`, 23 records timestamped at time `t + 5 minutes`, 33 records at time `t + 10 minutes`.

Controller Two might have 30 records timestamped at time `(t + 2 minutes) + 10 minutes`, 32 records timestamped at time `(t + 2 minutes) + 20 minutes`, 41 records timestamped at time `(t + 2 minutes) + 30 minutes` etcetera.

---

Assume now that the only information you have is the set of all timestamps and a count of how many records appeared at each timestamp.  That is to say, you don't know `i)` which sets of records were produced by which controller, `ii)` the collection interval of each controller or `ii)` the total number of controllers.  Is there an algorithm which can decompose the set of all timestamps into individual subsets such that the variance in difference between consecutive (ordered) elements of each given subset is very close to 0, while adding any element from one subset `i` to another subset `j` would increase this variance?  Keep in mind, for this dataset, a single controller's "periodicity" could fluctuate by +/- a few seconds because of CPU timing/network latency etc.

My ultimate objective here is to establish `a)` how many controllers there are and `b)` the sampling interval of each controller.  So far I've been thinking about the problem in terms of periodic functions, so perhaps there are some decomposition methods from that area that could be useful.

The other point to make is that I don't need to know *which* controller each record came from, I just need to know the sampling interval of each controller.  So e.g. if there were two controllers that both started sampling at time `u`, and one sampled at 5-minute intervals and the other at 50-minute intervals, it would be hard to separate the two at the 50-minute mark because 5 is a factor of 50.  This doesn't matter, so long as I can garner enough information to work out the intervals of each controller despite these occasional overlaps.

Comment: Hm, or you could log the controller ID in the dataset ;)

Comment: You have to have more constraints than that, and be more specific about your objective function (the thing to optimize). For example, what if I just make an unbounded number of controllers which log once at a specific time, and then never log again? The variance will be zero in this case.

Comment: @nneonneo I don't control the data source unfortunately.  And you're right re. constraints.  In this scenario, the number of controllers is likely to be small, say <= 25, and the log interval is likely to be on the order of a few minutes up to a maximum of around an hour at a guess.  This is in a trace that spans a few weeks.

Comment: Is there anything in the records themselves that could reveal the controller's identity? Perhaps the values cluster around different values for each controller? You could try k-means in that case to tease apart the logs on the basis of something other than timestamps.

Comment: @nneonneo at the moment nothing obvious other than the timestamp pattern would seem to allude to a separation of controllers.  Doesn't mean it's not there though.  If decomposing by timestamp proves unsuccessful I'll dig a little deeper.

Comment: How many fields are logged? The more fields, the more likely the data can be analyzed as clusters.

Answer (score 1):

One basic approach would be to perform an FFT decomposition (or, if you're feeling fancy, a periodogram) of the dataset and look for peaks in the resulting spectrum. This will give you a crude approximation of the periods of the controllers, and may even give you an estimate of their number (and by looking at the height of the peaks, it can tell you how many records were logged).